# Can hacked language markers affect Masuda?

Tags: pokemon-x-y

Does a Ditto from an American cartridge with a JPN language marker still work with Masuda method? I don’t want to trade for one if people can just make JPN Ditto that won’t work.

I’ve been trying forever to get my shiny Rockruff but I’m way over odds. Did I trade for a garbage fake JPN ditto? Or am I just really unlucky?

Comment: Friendly reminder that just because you have a 1 in 6 chance for a die to land on 6, it doesn't mean you're guaranteed to get a 6 after 6 throws, nor after 12 throws, or even after 60 throws. It may be incredibly unlikely to never get a 6 in 60 throws, but the probability is never 0. In fact, you have a ~0.002% chance of never getting a single 6 in 60 throws. To put it in another way: out of 8 Billion humans, 141 976 would likely not get a single 6 after 60 throws.

Comment: Welcome to Arqade! Please, consider accepting the answer if it solved your problem.

Answer (score 4):

The Masuda method involves breeding two Pokémon created in games of different languages, and as long as that Ditto has JPN tag the game will accept it as Japanese, even if it's legit or not.

According to [Bulbapedia](https://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/Masuda_method):

> An internal marker on each Pokémon identifies their "original language". If the game recognizes the two Pokémon in the daycare as having different languages, then when an Egg is generated, the game will generate extra personality values in an attempt to find one that results in a Shiny Pokémon.

So your Ditto is suitable, imho. Also because quite every 6IV Ditto out there is a hacked one.

You may just be unlucky, I hatched hundreds of eggs obtained from my Japanese Ditto in Pokemon Y, and I **never** managed to get a shiny.